# JNI mapping structure in java

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have a dll which has a method for e.g `void abc(meth* myMeth)` and a structure

```
struct meth
{
  int a;
  char b[255]; 
}
```

The above code code is written in c. I need to map this to Java through JNI, and I am stuck. How can I pass a reference to the method `abc` as a pointer from a Java method, and how can I set the values of `a` and `b` and then pass back to Java again?
Need An Urgent Help....Thanks

Comment: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5446936

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923299/how-to-pass-c-structs-back-and-forth-to-java-code-in-jni/4002158#4002158

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if this is an option for you, but consider using some **higher level framework** for managing the low-level details of JNI for you. Two options:

- [JNAerator](http://code.google.com/p/jnaerator/), see also "[Structs](http://code.google.com/p/jnaerator/wiki/CToJavaTransformation#Structs)" chapter in reference documentation.
- [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/), see also "[Structures and unions](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIG.html#SWIG_nn31)" chapter in reference documentation.

Personally I have used JNAerator and found it really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There is no mapping between Java classes and C structs (not sure about how JNA handles this); you'll have to create a Java class with the same members as your C struct and write C functions to convert between them.

Comment: @lhballoti...i have done with this process and i think it mapped quite well.