# Java to C object passing

Tags: java, android, struct, java-native-interface, ioctl

I have C code that call a kernel module and I want to pass a struct to it. This seems doable ex -
[char device catch multiple (int) ioctl-arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849445/char-device-catch-multiple-int-ioctl-arguments)

However I am invoking the c code through java JNI. It was said C struct mapping is to Java object. so am passing an object to the C native function.

Here is my JNI c function

```
  JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_context_test_ModCallLib_reNice
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jobject obj){

     // convert objcet to struct  
     // call module through IOCTL passing struct as the parameter
  }
```

How should I get a struct from obj?

EDIT: here is the object that I am passing,

```
class Nice{

    int[] pids;
    int niceVal;

    Nice(List<Integer> pID, int n){
        pids = new int[pID.size()];
        for (int i=0; i < pids.length; i++)
        {
            pids[i] = pID.get(i).intValue();
        }
        niceVal = n;
    }
}
```

the struct I want to have is this,

```
struct mesg {
     int pids[size_of_pids];
     int niceVal;
};
```

How should I approach?

Comment: The C struct you have to pass to the kernel module is filled up java side?

Comment: Yes I think this is easy isn't it? than passing the data to C and creating the struct?

Comment: any idea on how to get the struct from the object passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use JNI methods to access the fields, for example:

```
//access field s in the object
jfieldID fid = (env)->GetFieldID(clazz, "s", "Ljava/lang/String;");
if (fid == NULL) {
    return; /* failed to find the field */
}

jstring jstr = (env)->GetObjectField(obj, fid);
jboolean iscopy;
const char *str = (env)->GetStringUTFChars(jstr, &iscopy);
if (str == NULL) {
    return; // usually this means out of memory
}

//use your string
...

(env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jstr, str);

...

//access integer field val in the object
jfieldID ifld = (env)->GetFieldID(clazz, "val", "I");
if (ifld == NULL) {
    return; /* failed to find the field */
}
jint ival = env->GetIntField(obj, ifld);
int value = (int)ival;
```

There are member functions in the `JNIEnv` class to do whatever you need: to read and modify member variables of the class, to invoke methods and even to create new classes.  Have a look at the [JNI Specifications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html) for more details.

Comment: My object has an int array and an int how to do it then?

Comment: @kani I updated my answer to show how to get an integer field.  Getting an array is not much more complicated.  Go through the documentation - everything is in there.  Please don't expect other to do it for you.

Comment: Thakz Aleks G :) now the example looks simple.. Will it be possible to map the object in to struct? (I mean without accessing objects fields)

Comment: @kani No, you cannot "map" the object to a struct.  You can retrieve all fields and create a `struct` in C to make your life easier, yet you'll need to retrieve values of each field using JNI functions.

Comment: Yes and thankz. It looks like that too..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015121/jni-mapping-structure-in-java However I will have to have a int array inside the struct, which is of size of the objects array size. Which may change from time to time..

Comment: How can I specify the size for the array inside the struct?

Comment: @kani You will need to use JNI function `GetArrayLength` to determine the length of the array; then you can use the result when declaring your struct.

Comment: jfieldID ifld2 = (env)->GetIntArrayElements(clazz, "pids", NULL); This is wrong ryt? I have the array inside the object how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually copy the fields from the object. You can call [JNI methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#wp16536) to get the value of the fields by name. It might be easier to pass the fields themselves into the method instead of passing an object.