# Get Struct object in Java from C++

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I have **C++** struct:

```
typedef struct FunctionArgs
{
    char* url;
    char* info;
    int   id;
    bool  isWorking;
}
```

And **C++** function, which as an argument get `FunctionArgs` struct, now I want to call from this function Java method and as argument to that method give `FunctionArgs` struct.

```
void func( const FunctionArgs& args )
{
    // Do some code ...

    env->CallObjectMethod( clazzObject, clazzMethod, args );

}
```

As you can see in `env->CallObjectMethod( clazzObject, clazzMethod, *args );` function as third argument I give `args` which is `FunctionArgs` struct object.

In **JAVA** I have class and function:

```
class JFunctionArgs 
{
    String url;
    String info;
    int   id;
    boolean  isWorking;
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public void func( JFunctionArgs args )
    {

    }
}
```

### I want to know

1. Can I do something that I do `env->CallObjectMethod( clazzObject, clazzMethod, args );`, I mean can I give struct object to CallObjectMethod as an argument ?
2. How can I get struct object in Java code func ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot.  Assuming you actually need to consume this data in both Java and C, you will need to marshal between the Java `Object` and the C `struct`.

In your JNI code, you will need to create a new Java object and populate its data.  For example:

```
jclass clazz = env->FindClass("JFunctionArgs");
jmethodID ctor = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "<init>", "()V");
jobject obj = env->NewObject(clazz, ctor);

jfieldID urlField = env->GetFieldID(clazz, "url", "Ljava/lang/String;");
env->SetObjectField(obj, urlField, env->NewString(functionArgs.url));
```

...etc.

(If, however, you only need to modify the `struct`'s data in C, you can simply return a pointer to it and treat it as an opaque `long` in Java.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but you have to map the values yourself. You should take a look at this question: [How to pass C structs back and forth to Java code in JNI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923299/how-to-pass-c-structs-back-and-forth-to-java-code-in-jni).