# How to pass a c structure from native c library to java and access its elements

Tags: android

I have a structure defined in my native c library and i want to pass it to the java. In java then i want to access this structure elements. How to do this. Can anybody explain me with one example showing both c and java code. I will definitely appreciate for the help. Please help me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Java object in your C code and populate it with the data from the C struct. See the accepted answer for [How to pass C structs back and forth to Java code in JNI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923299/how-to-pass-c-structs-back-and-forth-to-java-code-in-jni) for more details.