# Is it possible to bind and access c struct members from java code?

Tags: java, android, c

We need to integrate some C file functions from java android code. Each c function accepts some raw binary data (byte stream) as input parameter, processes and returns pointer to c struct (union struct) that is defined in c file. Is it possible to create some java structure and bind it to c struct? Currently, extraction of returned data (returned c structs) is performed extracting byte by byte in java code, not by accessing struct members directly.

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923299/how-to-pass-c-structs-back-and-forth-to-java-code-in-jni

Comment: You need to look at the JNI - the *Java Native Interface*.  I would stay away from the NDK (Native Development Kit) if I were you.

Comment: Thanks for info, probably missed that post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of the specifics, but I think the [Java Native Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/) is your best bet.